# Changes in ML module in opencv from 3.0.0-beta to 3.0.0 (and rc1)

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

In class EM in ml.hpp, 
This piece of code below exists in 3.0.0-dev, 3.0.0-alpha but doesn't exist in 3.0.0 and 3.0.0-rc1 . The documentation for 3.0.0-dev says this exists †

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W_MAP Params
{
public:
    explicit Params(int nclusters=DEFAULT_NCLUSTERS, int covMatType=EM::COV_MAT_DIAGONAL,
        const TermCriteria& termCrit=TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS,
                                                              EM::DEFAULT_MAX_ITERS, 1e-6));
CV_PROP_RW int nclusters;
    CV_PROP_RW int covMatType;
    CV_PROP_RW TermCriteria termCrit;
};
```

Did opencv change a freaking library in the middle of a major release ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: "Did opencv change a freaking library in the middle of a major release " - yea. they weren't afaraid of that ;) all Params structs were removed in favour of direct get/set() methods, [here's it for EM](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d1/dfb/classcv_1_1ml_1_1EM.html)

Comment: The whole 3.0.0 release has been such a mess. I should have stuck to 2.4.x for longer .. Anyways. Thanks for the update.

Comment: i'm actually thinking the opposite - the 2.4 (c-style mess) should have been erased far earlier ;)

Comment: Yeah i had the same feeling, there were a lot of new additions and cleaner code in a lot of places. Hence I moved to 3.0.0. But you can't just change things in between builds where someone's code fails ! I'll stick to beta for a while. And xfeatures included, i feel was just too much modularization to make sense, atleast to me.